# How to integrate python with a Xamarin Android App for web-scraping

Tags: c#, python, xamarin, web-scraping, mobile

Me and a friend had an idea to build some kind of web-scraping software and eventually we settled for a mobile app (Android). The main idea is: We provide the user with a list of music festivals, the user selects one and when he does, a list of the current confirmed artists for that festival is displayed (we want it to display an up-to-date list). The list is retrieved via python scripts (note that the goal is not deployment or profit (at least right now), thus this very summarized explanation).

My question is, how would I go about integrating the python scripts with the mobile application? At this moment I know you can call them with C# but I'm not sure if that would work on a mobile environment. Plus I saw someone saying one should host the scripts on a web server and then execute them via API calls but the person didn't expand and I'm not sure how to do that.

Any insight on the matter or useful references would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Scraping info together in an app seems like a very unusual and difficult thing to do, not least because if the web sites they are scraping change, the scripts would need adapting.
If you have a server, it can do all the scraping, and provide the info your app need, in a format your app understand.  You can get a virtual server cheaply at, for example DigitalOcean.   Even the very cheapest and lowest specced one would likely be sufficient

Comment: @jdoer1997 yes I am aware of the risks of this idea but, again, it's merely for fun and experimentation. The application is mostly for our own use and we're trusting that, due to the nature of the websites, their structure will remain the same for quite a long period. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C# using HttpClient and HtmlAgilityPack;
You would need:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

Make methods like this:

```
public static HtmlNode GetNodeById(HttpClient client, string url, string divId)
{
    string pageHtml = "";
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            pageHtml =  content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }

    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(pageHtml);
    HtmlNode node = doc.GetElementbyId(divId);
    return node;
}
```

And call like this (where "musiciansDiv" is the div that contains the info your app needs):

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var musicians = GetNodeById(client, "http://gigs.example.com", "musiciansDiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're making this app for yourself and don't want to get too involved, you'll find some useful information in [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-controlling-your-pc-with-your-phonesusing-tcpip-protocol/).

The idea is to write a small C# server that will receive and send data to your mobile app without any problems. Then you can simply make the Python code write data to files and the C# server just reads that data and sends it to the mobile app, that's it!

Of course, this isn't a professional approach, but if you're interested in simplicity, this option is for you. Also a big plus is that the C# console application (in your case it will be the server) is also saved as an `.exe` file when compiling. This means that you can simply go to `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp*.*`, copy all the files from there into your Python project, and run the `.exe` file through Python.